# How can one-form be represented as multidimensional array?

Tags: differential-geometry

I learned that tensor is a [multidimensional array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#As_multidimensional_arrays) obeying certain transformation rules. Besides, [one-form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form) is an order $1$ covariant tensor.

Therefore, my question is, how to write the differential $\partial_i$, being a one-form, as a multidimensional array? To to each index at each position, we assign an operator, rather than a number, right?

Comment: If by $\partial_i$ you mean $\partial/\partial x^i$, this is a vector field, not a $1$-form.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}$
$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$
$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$

## TLDR

Roughly, yes. Just one note: the differential $\d$ is not a one-form. It is an operator that takes functions and turns them into one-forms.

This said, when one needs to do calculations in coordinates, one chooses a local coordinate system $(U,x)$ and then it is often useful to write components in matrix form. The most common convention leads us to *represent* the exterior differential $\d$ as a row-matrix of differential operators.
$$\begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1} \dots\frac{\partial}{\partial x^m}\end{bmatrix}$$

---

As said above, this is just one of many possible conventions. The specific way you do this depends on which convention you use for arranging components of vectors into matrices.

Take a chart $(U,x)$ in a real $m$-dimensional smooth manifold $M$. This induces an isomorphism between the space of local vector fields $\Gamma\,TU$ and the $m$-tuples of smooth local functions $(C^{\infty}U)^{m}$.

The same chart $(U,x)$ also induces an isomorphism between the space of local covector fields $\Gamma\,T^{*}U$ (a.k.a. local one-forms $\Omega^{1}U$) and $(C^{\infty}U)^{m}$.

By virtue of these isomorphisms is that one often says that "a (local) vector field is a tuple of (local) functions" (and the same with one-forms).

Now if for some reason we want to use matrices to represent our local objects, then the most common convention (in my experience) is to map $(C^{\infty}U)^{m}$ into the spaces of matrices of local functions: $\M_{m\times1}C^{\infty}U$ in the case of vector fields, and $\M_{1\times m}C^{\infty}U$ in the case of one-forms.

The reason to do this is so that matrix multiplication $\M_{1\times m}C^{\infty}U\times \M_{m\times 1}C^{\infty}U\to C^{\infty}U$ mimics the behaviour of the natural pairing $\Omega^{1}U\times \Gamma\,TU\to C^{\infty}U$.

Then, because we are representing our one-forms by row matrices of functions (elements of $\M_{1\times m}C^{\infty}U$), the (at least for me) obvious choice is to locally represent the exterior differential operator $\d:C^{\infty}M\to\Omega^{1}M$ with a row matrix of local differential operators as above.

But please note that the convention I described is not the only one. If you want to check other possible conventions, you can take a look at [the wiki article on matrix calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus). In my opinion it is a mess haha. So, personally, if I am doing calculations in coordinates, I find it easier to simply expand the sumations --especially when I am dealing with tensors of valence higher than $2$.